# Web URL in C# 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-status-code-401

I am trying to hit the Web URL from Dev Remote server.

```
var myRequet = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
```

In the response, I got an error

> "The remote server returned an rerror : (401) Unauthorized".

When I hit the url in the browser, the url is asking me for username and password. I gave it and I can access the url. Do I need to use Default credentials to open the Url from C# code?

Thanks

Comment: The error suggests authorization issue, but you can add try.. catch block and identify what is the actual error.

Comment: you can try with postman (chrome tool)  too to get the error or result

Comment: The endpoint you are trying to call requires authorisation which you are not providing. Look up the api docs on the endpoint and what they require for authorisation.

Answer (score 0):

this is basic Authorization
set header "Authorization" with value "Basic [base64({username}:{pasword})]"

sample:

```
myRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic "+Base64Encode("your Username"+":"+"your Password");
//
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
  var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
  return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```